# How can you access the contents of Android Emulator databases?

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I've read the answer to a question as to how to access the contents of the databases, however I cannot seem to get it to work on my machine. Here is the shell log:

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb -s emulator-5554 shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.demo.notepad2/databases/notes
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.demo.notepad2/databases/notes
SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .tables
.tables
sqlite> ^C
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools>
```

SQLite simply echos my commands back to me, even although the Eclipse file browser tells me it exists. If I use the sqlite3 tool and use ".tables" the commands are accepted.

Is the SQLite syntax different through the emulator is am I missing something?

(Sorry for so many questions, there doesn't seem to be much coherent documentation on Android!)

Thanks!

Comment: "SQLite simply echos my commands back to me, even although the Eclipse file browser tells me it exists. If I use the sqlite3 tool and use ".tables" the commands are accepted." These two sentences appear to say the exact opposite things: it simultaneously works and does not work. Could you please clarify what you mean here? Also, if you format your source code and output listings using the "code sample" icon in the toolbar (101 010), they will be somewhat easier for us to read.

Comment: I mean to say, if I run the code above (in the Android shell) it echos back, however if I run the sqlite3 tool from the Windows command line and create a database, all commands work as expected.

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 13):

I can tell you that it works fine for me on Android 2.0.1:

```
$ adb shell
# cd /data/data/apt.tutorial   
# ls
lib
databases
shared_prefs
# cd databases
# ls
lunchlist.db
# sqlite3 lunchlist.db
SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .tables
android_metadata  restaurants     
sqlite> .exit
# exit
```

You can always download the database file using DDMS or `adb pull` and use a desktop SQLite client to examine it. For example, I use the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox.

Also, bear in mind that SQLite has no default file extension, so if your database is not `notes` but `notes.db` or `notes.sqlite` or something, you'll need to specify the extension.

Also also, I have not tried this on Windows, and there's a possibility that there is something goofy with the Windows command prompt and the limited shell available on Android devices that is causing your difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to issue sqlite3 statements from command line use something like

```
$ adb -e shell sqlite3 -batch /data/data/com.example.dbsample/databases/db '.tables'
android_metadata

$ adb -e shell sqlite3 -batch /data/data/com.example.dbsample/databases/db 'select * from android_metadata;'
en_US
```

the obvious advantages are that you can rely on your shell history and you can use this in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and discovered that contrary to the documentation you shouldn't put the ".db" extension on the database file name.

Note: I'm using win7 and 2.1 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ,spent almost an hour ,posting  here so that it will save someone else time ,check if you have given the correct filename along with the extension, there are two files under the databases folder myDB.db and myDB.db-journal and when i ran 
"sqlite3 /data/data/com.my.package/databases/myDB" 

and
 
.tables 
listed nothing, sqlite3 created a new db with the name myDB , it did not open myDB.db